# TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance *On an Object*

Tags: javascript, object, spread-syntax

I have the following code as part of grabbing data from a query and appending it to a local state that is stored as an object. However, this following code using the `spread` operator (`...`) is not working and returns the following error
`TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance`

```
console.log("HIT LINE 96")
console.log(comment.videoId, "LINE 97")
console.log(comment, "LINE 98")
newComments = {...newComments}
console.log("LINE 101")
```

where

`comment` ===

```
{"__typename": "Comment", "content": "He did in fact step up", "createdAt": "2022-10-26T14:22:32.117Z", "id": "a2dd317a-1791-4d79-920f-4fc347fa5e0a", "videoId": "step_up"}
```

and
`newComments` ===

```
{"test": "empty"}
```

The point of this code is to take a long complicated query object and bring it into the state-- so while not relevant to the problem it sheds some more context on why I'm performing this operation in the first place

```
useEffect(() => {
        // Local variable to track new additions
        let newComments = commentIds

        // Goes through ever Comment
        plan.comments.forEach( comment => {

            console.log("----------------------")
            console.log(comment.videoId, "LINE 88")
            console.log(commentIds, "LINE 89")

            // If a video id alredy has comments, add this to it
            if (commentIds[(comment.videoId)]){
                console.log("HIT LINE 93")
                newComments = {...newComments, [comment.videoId]: [...newComments[comment.videoId], comment]}
            }

            // If a video id does not yet have a comment
            else{
                console.log("HIT LINE 96")
                console.log(comment.videoId, "LINE 97")
                console.log(comment, "LINE 98")
                newComments = {...newComments}
                console.log("LINE 101")
                newComments = {...newComments, [comment.videoId]: comment}
            }
        })

        setCommentIds( commentIds => ({...newComments}))
    }, [client1])
```

Comment: You are doing both `[...newComments]` and `{ ...newComments }` which doesn't make sense. `commentIds` - this name suggest that it's an array not an object, what is it then?

Comment: `newComments` is an object wherein each value is going to be an array. So if it worked as expected, it would look something like this ```{step_up: [<comment1>, <comment2>], toe_touches: [<comment1>], jumping_jacks: [<comment1>, <comment2>]}``` so whenever you see [...newComments] its always followed by a key, i.e. `[...newComments.step_ups, <whatever else>]` instead of just `[...newComments]`. That is not the issue right now, however, as it breaks at this line... `newComments = {...newComments}`

Comment: You can't do `[ ...name]` with an object. This line `setCommentIds( commentIds => ([...newComments]))` should be `setCommentIds( commentIds => ({ ...newComments }))`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski good catch! That was a typo on my part, but the error unfortunately is still before that

Comment: Please update the question with the actual code.

Comment: This is the actual code @Barmar

Comment: You said "That was a typo on my part". Please post the code without the typo, since you say it still fails.

Comment: Oh yes, the edits were made, that code is correct now

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure WHY this worked, so an explanation there would be great, but I attempted the following solution and now the code works perfectly

```
useEffect(() => {
        // Local variable to track new additions
        let newComments = commentIds

        // Goes through ever Comment
        plan.comments.forEach( comment => {

            // If a video id alredy has comments, add this to it
            if (commentIds[(comment.videoId)]){
                newComments = {...newComments, [comment.videoId]: [...newComments[comment.videoId], comment]}
            }

            // If a video id does not yet have a comment
            else{
                newComments = {...{...newComments}}
                newComments = {...newComments, [comment.videoId]: [{...comment}]}
            }
        })

        // Sets the overall object
        setCommentIds( commentIds => ({...{...newComments}}))
    }, [client1])
```

Main change being `newComments = {...newComments}` becoming `newComments = {...{newComments}}`